# What does "28" prefix stands for in Microsoft Bot Framework's App Id (Teams)

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am working on Microsoft Bot framework and when I delete bot from the team I am receiving `teamMemberRemoved` event and when I am trying to get removed users from `activity.MembersRemoved` there is user with following ID - `28:<appId>`.

I have also found out some solutions on GitHub which is dealing with bot user like this:
`new ChannelAccount("28:" + botCredentials.MicrosoftAppId);`

So, I would like to know what does `28` stands for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at anything your bot receives from Teams, such as a message from a user, or teamMemberRemoved event, etc., there are various id "types" that are at play. As an example, here is a sample conversationUpdate event:

```
{
    "membersAdded": [
        {
            "id": "28:[bot app id]"
        }
    ],
    "type": "conversationUpdate",
    "timestamp": "2019-10-31T12:20:31.483Z",
    "id": "f:[event id]",
    "channelId": "msteams",
    "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/",
    "from": {
        "id": "29:[conversation id]",
        "aadObjectId": "[user AAD Id]"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "isGroup": true,
        "conversationType": "channel",
        "tenantId": "[Tenant Id]",
        "id": "19:[group or channel id]@thread.skype"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "id": "28:[bot app id]",
        "name": "[bot name]"
    },
    "channelData": {
        "team": {
            "id": "19:[some id]@thread.skype",
            "name": "Indoor Soccer",
            "aadGroupId": "[AAD Group Id]"
        },
        "eventType": "teamMemberAdded",
        "tenant": {
            "id": "[Tenant Id again]"
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, you can see a whole bunch of "Id"s, like the Tenant Id, Conversation Id, User's Azure AD Id, etc. Teams has a specific prefix format for some of these though, like "29:" is how a regular user's "Teams" Id starts, "19" is a Channel or group Id, etc. Bots start with "28:", and then they have a unique Guid Id, but in the case of a Bot, it's Guid Id is the same Id as it's App Id in the Azure Bot Registration, so it's predictable. That means if, for example, you're sending a proactive message and you need to set the "From" user's Id, you can compose it with "28:" + your App Id, which you likely have in a config file in order to deal with the encryption/decryption for your bot's messages.